# XSSFWorkbook, XSSFSheet not working - NetBeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, apache-poi, netbeans-8, xssf

I downloaded the *POI 3.11* package from the Apache repositories website, added them to my project. After that I added *xmlbeans*, *ooxml-schemas*, but still my NetBeans 8.0.1 IDE shows an error when I declare `XSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFSheet`.

Can anybody help me here? as I am not much of a core Java guy, so treat me as a novice in this domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty awkward but a truth also. 

I found the solution, and it is in my **NetBeans 8.0.2 IDE**, which is when I manually typed the following code in the IDE :-

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");
```

it **showed an error**. But when I went on and clicked the **suggestion**(CTRL + Space)
 provided by the IDE it miraculously **worked**, but I do not have a logical clue about the thing though :)
Hope it will be of help for **NetBeans Apache POI Developers**.
Thanks!!!